# is in.something.somethingelse not a valid package name in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

is `in.something.somethingelse` not a valid package name in kotlin?

Package name was auto-generated by Android Studio for a flutter project with kotlin support.

Error: Package name must be a '.'-separated identifier list

Answer (score 4):

`in` is a keyword.

If you really like to use this package name, you can do it like this:

```
package `in`.something.somethingelse
```

Answer (score -2):

This error comes due to the "in" which is one of the keyword of kotlin
you try this

```
1. Find "MainActivity.kt" on the kotlin folder
2. Change package in.something.somethingelse to package `in`.something.somethingelse
```

if in case it not work then try to upgrade latest Kotlin version